# Как в Apache задать переадресацию и ошибки?

Tags: apache

Как в Apache сделать кодировку `utf-8` и перенаправить на `index` запросы и как сделать страницу ошибки в нем?

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! несвязанные вопросы следует задавать **отдельными** вопросами. оставьте, пожалуйста, один вопрос, внеся правку (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Переадресация на index.php

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Файл ошибки через htaccess `ErrorDocument 404 /error404.php`

Comment: Спасибо до этого был похожий но почему то не реагировал

Comment: а без кодировки работает, она не нужна?

Comment: @СеменНемяев по желанию